# Xubuntu VMware Player missing vmrun utility

Tags: xubuntu, vmware-player

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and I have installed VMware Player from the official website. VM Player runs fine, no problem. But I can't find utility `vmrun`, it's not found anywhere in the system.

Do I have to install it alone from another package or how can I get it ? I thought it comes with the VMware Player basic installation.

Thanks for any hints in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix111_vmrun_command.pdf):

> The vmrun utility installs with Workstation and VMware Fusion.
>
> For use with remote product platforms, you can obtain vmrun by installing the VIX standalone libraries, available free of charge on the VMware download site.

That's not very specific, but you can download the packages [here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0%7CPLAYER-602%7Cdrivers_tools) (and select the version you need). Then install the VIX API according to [these instructions](http://www.vmware.com/products/beta/ws/vix_api/ReferenceGuide/intro.html#0_84125) (download step included for informational purposes, since you can download from previous link)

> Download the tar-gzip package. For example:
>
> ```
> wget http://www.vmware.com/downloads/server/VMware-vix-110068.i386.tar.gz
> ```
>
> As superuser, extract the package:
>
> ```
> sudo tar zxpf VMware-vix-110068.i386.tar.gz
> ```
>
> Change directory and, as superuser, run the VMware installer:
>
> ```
> cd vmware-vix-distrib
> sudo ./vmware-install.pl
> ```
>
> Read the EULA and type "yes" if you agree to its terms. You can accept most defaults by typing Enter when prompted.
>
> To uninstall the VIX API, run the vmware-uninstall-vix.pl script. The
> uninstaller is at /usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-vix.pl by default.

Comment: URL is dead :-(

Comment: Working URL: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0|PLAYER-600-A|drivers_tools

Answer (score 0):

direct download links are of this format now https://dlm3.vmware.com/akdlm/software/open-source/VMware-VIX-1.14.0-oss.tgz

Comment: Frodik asked where is `vmrun` utility?