# Install VMWare including vmrun

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

**Context:**

I have to run a virtual machine with **VMWare Player** (version 16) on an Ubuntu server (version 18.04) without being able to run the GUI (the server has no display). The virtual machine has already been created, I just need to import the `.ovf` file and power it on. I read on several posts that the best way is to use an utility called **vmrun**. The problem is that it is not installed together with VMWare, or at least it is not with the installation I did (if it can help, I used [this guide](https://noviello.it/come-installare-vmware-workstation-player-su-ubuntu-20-04/), it's in italian but the commands should be easily understandable).

So, I tried to install vmrun it in several ways (for example by following the instructions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458198/xubuntu-vmware-player-missing-vmrun-utility)), but I wasn't able to do it. Moreover, every article/guide that I find seems pretty outdated. I even tried to install the [VIX API](https://www.vmware.com/products/beta/ws/vix_api/ReferenceGuide/), but I wasn't able to do that either (and, even if I could, I wouldn't know how to use it).

**Question:**

Is there a way to install a version of VWMare Player that includes vmrun? If yes, how? If no, how can I install vmrun separately?

Answer (score 0):

The `vmrun` utility is part of the `open-vm-tools` package. You can install it pretty painlessly:

0. Connect to the server (if you're not already connected)
1. Ensure `apt` is up to date:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install the package:

   ```
   apt install open-vm-tools
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** If you need these tools on a Linux installation that has a GUI, you can use `open-vm-tools-desktop`.</sup>
3. Restart/Boot the VMs

The services that need to run will be automatically started and continue to persist across reboots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your instructions but unfortunately, if I try to type `vmrun` I get `Command 'vmrun' not found`. Am I missing something?